# How do I trace a custom allocator using xperf's heap profiling tools?

Tags: memory, winapi, etw, xperf

xperf (part of Windows Performance Analysis Toolkit) is very helpful in tracking memory usage with its heap analysis.  However, my app uses a custom allocator -- it grabs chunks via VirtualAlloc directly and manages its own heap.  I'd like to generate HeapAlloc/HeapFree/etc. events myself from my own allocation functions, so that I can use the tools as is, without having to define a bunch of custom ETW events.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [leakdiag](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Tools.aspx)